# Same random values are inserted into a collection repeatedly C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop

This might be silly, but I'm stuck on this. I have a list with a property that has a default value. What I will do is update the property in the list using a random value, and then store the list with the new values on it inside a Dictionary. The dictionary's key is int, which represents the year, and the value is the list. The problem is only the last set of random values are stored in the dictionary. Please check my code

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 2, 3 ,4};
    Dictionary<int, List<TestClass>> testAllYearsList = new Dictionary<int, List<TestClass>>();
    int year = 2018;
    var random = new Random();

    List<TestClass> testList = new List<TestClass>();

    testList = db;//assuming the values here are fetched from db

    foreach(var number in numbers){

        testList.ForEach(x => {
            x.test = random.NextDouble();
        });
        testAllYearsList.Add(year - number, testList);

    }

    foreach(KeyValuePair<int, List<TestClass>> entry in testAllYearsList)
    {
            foreach(var xx in entry.Value){
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + "-------" + xx.test);
            }
    }
}
public class TestClass{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public double test{get;set;}
}
```

The above code results are like these:

```
2018-------0.702259658231521
2018-------0.517733022811698
2017-------0.702259658231521
2017-------0.517733022811698
2016-------0.702259658231521
2016-------0.517733022811698
2015-------0.702259658231521
2015-------0.517733022811698
2014-------0.702259658231521
2014-------0.517733022811698
```

What I'm expecting is something like this:

```
2018-------0.232323558231521
2018-------0.679072365236698
2017-------0.702259658231545
2017-------0.834268732412351
2016-------0.465468889231561
2016-------0.323423456811698
2015-------0.125332658231528
2015-------0.347588566678699
2014-------0.734758565656521
2014-------0.854544444571690
```

UPDATE: I tried this but still it's getting me the same issue.

```
foreach(var number in numbers){
    var newTestList = new List<TestClass>();
    foreach(var xx in testList){
    newTestList.Add(xx);        
    }
    newTestList.ForEach(x => {
        x.test = random.NextDouble();
    });
    testAllYearsList.Add(year - number, newTestList);

}
```

Comment: You keep editing the same `testList` and the members of `testAllYearsList` contain references to that lists items

Comment: You have the same 2 objects you keep modifying, the last random number for each wins. Try executing this statement: `Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(testAllYearsList[2018], testAllYearsList[2017]));`, you have 1 list that you add to your dictionary with different year keys, but it's the same list instance and thus the same two TestClass instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the same `testList` with the same `TestClass` objects you're adding *references to the same objects* to `testAllYearsList`, one possible way of fixing this would be to add a new `testList` with new objects each time:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    Dictionary<int, List<TestClass>> testAllYearsList = new Dictionary<int, List<TestClass>>();
    int year = 2018;
    var random = new Random();

    foreach (var number in numbers) {
        List<TestClass> testList = new List<TestClass> {
            new TestClass { test = 0.2 },
            new TestClass { test = 1.5 }
        };
        testList.ForEach(x => {
            x.test = random.NextDouble();
        });
        testAllYearsList.Add(year - number, testList);

    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<TestClass>> entry in testAllYearsList) {
        foreach (var xx in entry.Value) {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + "-------" + xx.test);
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
2018-------0.961755354405267
2018-------0.285138806926617
2017-------0.249302806914459
2017-------0.68261938015121
2016-------0.998315326403042
2016-------0.692115324871668
2015-------0.822671521838136
2015-------0.0111894570343147
2014-------0.745275680788455
2014-------0.0539408922446616
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have two instances of `TestClass`, you've added references to those two instance to each entry in the dictionary. When one instance of `TestClass` has its property updated all references to that `TestClass` instance see the same value.

Inside the loop over `numbers` create new instances of `TestClass` and see your expected behaviour:

```
testList = new List<TestClass> {
   new TestClass { test = random.NextDouble() },
   new TestClass { test = random.NextDouble() }
}
testAllYearsList.Add(year - number, testList);
```

Comment: If for example the TestClass does contain other property aside from "test" and the list is already populated from the db. What should I do to update only the test variable to have unique random values?

Comment: @fmpsagara This comment is not enough space to explain the difference between value semantics and reference semantics. Understanding the difference will explain why you need a different instance if you want to have distinct state. Short answer: adding a reference to a list does not copy/clone/replicate/duplicate the added object/

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working now. Here's what I changed:

```
foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            var newTestList = new List<TestClass>();
            foreach (var xx in testList)
            {
                newTestList.Add(new TestClass
                {
                    name = xx.name,
                    test = xx.test
                });
            }
            newTestList.ForEach(x => {
                x.test = random.NextDouble();
            });
            testAllYearsList.Add(year - number, newTestList);

        }
```

So adding `xx` directly to the `newTestList` would not resolve the issue. Instead, I need to create new `TestClass`, map the values from the `xx`, and then add it into `newTestList`.

Thanks a lot to those who took their time to help. Without those ideas, I couldn't get this working.